# Open ASCII file and make a map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, matrix, ascii, raster

I am a new R user and I would like your help. When I imported my file and change the number of rows (401) and columns (701) it did not change in the raster. Also I need to change the extent and the result got worse (see the map below).

I imported the .asc to R using the following script:

```
nrows = 401
ncols = 701
df1 <- read.table("test.txt" , header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
r.mat <- as.matrix(df1, nrow = nrows, ncol=ncols)
r <- rast(r.mat, extent=c(19497.75, 720497.8, 219499.8, 620499.8))
plot(r)
```

here is the test file I used: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4n7xw9qzav3dsv/test.txt?dl=0

Map: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/493AI.png)

Please, could someone help and tell me where is my mistake?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your file seems to contain a mixture of tabs and spaces, so it can be read in with scan. The function `as.matrix` should be replaced by `matrix` if you want to specify the number of rows and columns.

```
nrows = 401
ncols = 701
df1 <- scan("test.txt" , sep = "")

r.mat <- matrix(df1, nrow = nrows, ncol=ncols, byrow=TRUE)

r <- rast(r.mat, extent=c(19497.75, 720497.8, 219499.8, 620499.8))

plot(log(r))  #changed to log scale so values visible
```

Then your code seems to work (after loading `terra` package)

[image: Output plot]

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I am still getting only one column instead of 701. Therefore, it is still making a similar map than the one I posted.

Comment: Hopefully sorted now, although it does look like there are some numbers in `r.mat[401,]` that are an order of magnitude bigger than the rest of the matrix (and `inf`s) that might suggest this row of data is different to the others

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I have to check this discrepant values.